# How to I set up the for loop so I can select one radio button per question?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[View of the Question and Radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigKP.png)

Php Laravel radiobutton selects only one radio button for all the given questions. How to I set up the for loop so I can select one radio button per question? I'm using eloquent ORM for setting up relationship between the tables.

```
                    <div class="card-header">{{$question->question_order}}{{"."}} {{ $question->question }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @foreach($question->options as $option)
                                @if(($question->type)=='c')
                                    <label class="container3">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{ $option->option }}
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                @elseif(($question->type)=='r')
                                    <label class="container3">
                                        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{ $option->option }}
                                        <span class="radio"></span>
                                    </label>                                
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            @if(($question->type)=='s')
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id=""></textarea>
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Use `name` attribute to same radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give unique name option wise to radio group or checkbox, for question wise group and store user response.

Change your for foreach loop as below:

```
@foreach($question->options as $option)
    @if(($question->type)=='c')
        <label class="container3">
            <input type="checkbox"  name="answer[{{$question->id}}]" value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{ $option->option }}
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    @elseif(($question->type)=='r')
        <label class="container3">
            <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]" value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{ $option->option }}
            <span class="radio"></span>
        </label>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Here i give name question id wise